# Pq ta dando esse erro -> error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token

Tags: c, compilação

Fiz um algoritmo para determinar se um número é primo ou não, mas ao compilar está dando esse erro ao compilar no próprio terminal do ubuntu.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int n, i, divisivel;

 printf("Digite um numero para saber se eh primo: \n");
 scanf("%i", &n);

for(i = n, i >= 0, i--){

            if (n%i == 0){
            divisivel =divisivel + 1;
        }


}

 if(divisivel <=2){
        printf("o numero %i eh primo!: \n", n);

 }else{

    printf("o numero %i não eh primo \n", n);
}
return (0);
}
```

Comment: No for, ao invés de usar vírgula `,`, troque por ponto e vírgula `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu for use `;` ao invés de vírgula. Assim:

```
for(i = n; i >= 0; i--){
   if (n%i == 0){
      divisivel =divisivel + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: então cara, eu percebi isso e arrumei, esta dando erro de excesso de ponto flutuante agora, não sei pq.